# Do Linux running as VM will use drivers of host OS?

Tags: linux, driver, vmware, virtualization

I am developing some application in Linux .This Linux is a virtual machine running in Windows, with the help of VMWare player. When my Linux application access the peripherals (say camera , network ..) , the access goes through the parent host machine's drivers (Here Windows)?

The idea is to know whether changing the Windows driver capabilities will affect my Linux application.

(The question is not about whether the data will flow through windows. It is about whether the corresponding windows driver get called - e.g for Linux Video, whether the corresponding Windows video driver will be invoked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way for the virtual machine to control the peripherals but via the drivers. Please note that you may have some settings in the VM that add more restrictions then the settings of the external driver, but for sure you will never have less.

Comment: the drivers here you mean the Windows Driver isn't it ? So the calls for Linux periperals(via linux driver) will go through the windows driver.